# Django Allauth very specific redirection after Facebook Social Signup

Tags: django, facebook, django-allauth

I know there are a few questions on the topic already but I have tried to implement those solutions and could not really solve my problem.

I am talking about social signup with allauth here, and facebook in particular.

DESIRED BEHAVIOR: after facebook signup I want user to go to my url "accounts:welcome", but when they simply login I want them to go to my LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL (which is the site's home page).
After looking here and there this is the code I came up with (writing my custom adapter)

settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = ("gamestream:home")
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "myproject.users.adapter.MySocialAccountAdapter"
```

adapter.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect


class MySocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):

    def save_user(self, request, sociallogin, form=None):
        print('OK11OK')
        super().save_user(request, sociallogin, form=form)
        return redirect(reverse('accounts:welcome'))

    def get_connect_redirect_url(self, request, socialaccount):
        print('OK22OK')
        assert is_authenticated(request.user)
        url = reverse('accounts:welcome')
        return url
```

Please assume that all links/settings are good as for example the console prints out 'OK11OK' when I create myself as a user via the facebook app. The fact is that the method get_connect_redirect_url never gets triggered as I never read 'OK22OK' on the console.
The user is created and I end up on the home page, which is not what I want.

So I thought that after the save_user method something else gets called as I can tell that I pass through accounts:welcome, but then end up on the home page.
I can tell this because if I return an incorrect url in the save_user method I get an error that is specific to that url on that line.

So, what is wrong here?
I think I might be overriding the wrong method but I have read all the code of the base SocialAccountAdapter and I can't see anything else that would be the right choice.

Just wanted to mention that as I have more control on the normal account signup (not social) I have achieved what I wanted.
Any ideas?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too, I found two methods:

**METHOD 1**

Django doesn't use redirection function of the DefaultSocialAccountAdapter, you'll have to override the get_signup_redirect_url function of DefaultAccountAdapter to achieve the result.

First you need to change the default adapter in settings.py:

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'users.adapter.MyAccountAdapter'
```

Then, just override the get_signup_redirect_url with your url:

```
# project/users/adapter.py
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
 
class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

def get_signup_redirect_url(self, request):
    return resolve_url('/your/url/')
```

**METHOD 2**

This is the easier one

If you take a look at the source code at DefaultAccountAdapter it says:

> Returns the default URL to redirect to after logging in.  Note
> that URLs passed explicitly (e.g. by passing along a `next`
> GET parameter) take precedence over the value returned here.

So, you can pass along a next parameter in your login template to force the redirection. Here is an example using Google social login:

```
{% load socialaccount %}
{% providers_media_js %}
{# your html tags #}
<body>
    <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' next='/success/url/' %}">SOCIAL LOGIN </a>
</body>
```

Of course you can personalize the next url (I'm refering to /success/url/) as you wish. You can pass a context variable with your desired url and put it there instead of that hardcoded url.